# lsof shows difference in open file descriptors in riak process

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, riak, lsof

When I am doing `lsof -l` it shows all open file descriptors (~180000), but when I am checking `lsof -lp pid` shows only ~1000. I know that process with pid `pid` has ~170000 file descriptors open.

Here are logs:

```
root@riak:/proc/3238# lsof -l | grep 3238 | wc -l
172923
root@riak:/proc/3238# lsof -lp 3238 | wc -l
1075
root@riak:/proc/3238# ls -la | wc -l
44
root@riak:/proc/3238# ls -la fd | wc -l
924
```

Why there is such difference?

Comment: Note that your `... | grep 3238 | ..` will also match `13238`, `23238`, `32380`, etc... It will also match parts of the `lsof` output that are not PIDs...

Comment: @twalberg I checked it, its not a case here

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What do you anticipate the proc directory to tell you about Riak functionality?